# Karate SSL and HashiCorp Vault Secret Engine

Tags: karate

Currently, I'm struggling with automation our API over SSL with Karate DSL, and the main problem is that I'm not able to automate this API without keeping that cert.pfx in some directory with below configuration:

// enable X509 certificate authentication with PKCS12 file 'certstore.pfx' and password 'certpassword'

- configure ssl = { keyStore: 'classpath:certstore.pfx', keyStorePassword: 'certpassword', keyStoreType: 'pkcs12' }

Is there any other approach to load the cert store? instead of using certstore.pfx form local directory/cloud/sftp dir?

I was thinking about creating a KeyStore java object(with chain certs& private key) and pass it to configuration instead of (pfx file) { keyStore: keyStoreObj, keyStorePassword: 'xxx' ..}, or some other memory object, which will provide all needed certs/keys to connect over SSL.

thanks for your advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Java interop: https://github.com/intuit/karate#calling-java

For example: you can implement some custom way to get the cert that you need and save it to `/tmp` and then use `file:/tmp/mycert.pfx` to load the cert.

It is up to you to implement in any way that you want. If you want to do something more advanced, consider extending the [`ApacheHttpClient`](https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-apache/src/main/java/com/intuit/karate/http/apache/ApacheHttpClient.java) - and tips on how to do this are provided [here](https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-mock-servlet#switching-the-http-client).

Answer (score 2):

Thank you Peter, so I decided to go to that advanced way, so decide to extend HttpClient, where I override configure(HttpConfig config, ScriptContext context) and decide to pass there KeyStore object, which was constructed before with certificates, which I got from HasiCorp Vault.

Btw Karate DSL is great!